# Receiving UDP broadcast data

Tags: ios, sockets, udp, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm trying to receive broadcast UDP datagrams on iOS. I started to use the [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) library which seems pretty good. I'm using it like this:

```
m_socket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[m_socket setIPv6Enabled:NO];

NSError* error = nil;
if (![m_socket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error])
    return log_warn(@"Failed to enable broadcast: %@.", error.description);
if (![m_socket bindToPort:43211 error:&error])
    return log_warn(@"Failed to bind to port: %@.", error.description);
if (![m_socket beginReceiving:&error])
    return log_warn(@"Failed to begin receiving.");
```

The result is that the didReceiveData callback seems not to be called.
I therefore tried to use regular socket API and it seems I can get some bytes: I simply used [this code](https://gist.github.com/chancyWu/8349411).

I am curious about why the CocoaAsyncSocket code above is not working. I tried to compare the two approaches by reading the internals of CocoaAsyncSocket but I'm still not able to find which difference is causing no byte to arrive. Am I missing something in the above code using CocoaAsyncSocket?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Like Failed to bind to port or etc?

Comment: No error. Not in the callback and not in the returned value.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a response? Please use WireShark to check if your packet is getting sent and you are getting a reply.

Comment: I used wireshark to confirm that datagrams are sent from the device to the broadcast address. But should I also expect datagrams from iOS to the device in UDP? There is no concept of "connection" and I only receive on iOS. Should I expect datagrams from iOS to the device anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the code in CocoaAsyncSocket I see that the member holding the reference to the delegate is weak. Therefore the reason why no callback and no error were received was that the delegate was freed. Storing a strong reference to the object was sufficient to get the data.